# Forbidden - CSRF token invalid with gorilla/csrf and Angular

Tags: angularjs, go, csrf

Full code example here: https://github.com/crosbymichael/not-dockers-ui/commit/15d133324d22e84e3c2839d19b112a96ced4dd66

I've wrapped the handler with CSRF.Protect(), Angular is finding the `_gorilla_csrf` cookie and passing it back as the `X-CSRF-Token` header, but I always receive invalid token errors on non-GET requests:

```
Forbidden - CSRF token invalid
```

Am I trying to use the gorilla/csrf incorrectly?

Edit: Simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var (
    mux         = http.NewServeMux()
    fileHandler = http.FileServer(http.Dir(""))
    h           http.Handler
    CSRF        = csrf.Protect(
                []byte("32-byte-long-auth-key"),
                csrf.HttpOnly(false),
                csrf.Secure(false),
    )
)
u, err := url.Parse("http://host/api")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
h = httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)

mux.Handle("/dockerapi/", http.StripPrefix("/dockerapi", h))
mux.Handle("/", fileHandler)

handler := CSRF(mux)
if err := http.ListenAndServe(*addr, handler); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

We serve static files from the server directly, and API requests pass through to an external backend. The app is an Angular SPA that often has multiple requests in flight to the API, but typically only has one non-GET request active at any time.

Comment: SO is not a code review site. Please update your question with the relavent code you want examined.

Comment: Raise an issue on the gorilla/csrf repository (I am the maintainer). I'm keen to improve the docs if you think there are gaps, but the examples should cover most use cases (the API is intentionally simple).